# Simulating virtual machine, have trouble with incrementing pc versus jumps

Tags: c, virtual-machine

I'm writing a virtual machine in C and I have all the various functions working, however I'm having trouble putting them together. Specifically I'm running into the problem that I need a way to increment the program counter without it interfering with the instructions that change what pc is pointing at like JMP, JPC, CAL, and RET. When I try to put in measures to cancel out pc++ like a PCvalueAfterJmp - 1 or `if` statements to not increment on those cases, it suddenly goes into an infinite loop which appears to be repeatedly going through the instructions.

This program reads in an input file and prints to the screen what instructions are being processed and the current state of the stack

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  int running = 1;
  int numInstructions = 0;
  int lineRun;
  int arcntr = 0;

  //Memory
  int stack[MAX_STACK_HEIGHT];
  instruction code[MAX_CODE_LENGTH];
  int arlist[MAX_STACK_HEIGHT];

  //Registers
  int sp=0;
  int bp=1;
  int pc=0;
  instruction ir;

  //Initializing ir
  ir.op = 0;
  ir.l = 0;
  ir.m = 0;

  //Initializing stack
  stack[1] = 0;
  stack[2] = 0;
  stack[3] = 0;

  //Reading the input file
  numInstructions = readFile(argc, argv, code);
  if(numInstructions < 0) //Exit with error if readFile returns invalid
    return 1;

  //show input code
  printFile(code, numInstructions);

  //setup and labeling
  printState(-1, ir, pc, bp, sp, stack, arlist);



  //Execution loop
  while(running)
    {
    lineRun = pc;

    //Fetch cycle
    ir = code[pc];

    //Execution cycle returns a nonzero to keep program running until end
    if(!execOp(&sp, &bp, &pc, ir, code, stack, arlist, &arcntr))
      running = 0;

    //if statement didn't work
    printState(lineRun, ir, pc, bp, sp, stack, arlist);
    //if (!(ir.op == 5 || ir.op == 7 || ir.op == 8 || (ir.op == 2 && ir.m == 0)))
    pc++;
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Here is my execution cycle

```
int execOp(int* sp, int* bp, int* pc, instruction ir, instruction code[],
           int stack[], int arlist[], int* arcntr){

  switch((opcode)ir.op){
  case LIT:
    stack[++(*sp)] = ir.m;
    break;

  case OPR:  //Operators
    switch((operator)ir.m){

    case RET:
      if(*bp == 1) //Kill the simulation if we're at the base level
        return 0;
      arlist[--(*arcntr)] = 0;
      *sp = *bp - 1;
      *pc = stack[*sp+3];
      *bp = stack[*sp+2];
      break;

    case NEG:
      stack[*sp] = -stack[*sp];
      break;

    case ADD:
      (*sp)--;
      stack[*sp] = stack[*sp] + stack[*sp+1];
      break;

    case SUB:
      (*sp)--;
      stack[*sp] = stack[*sp] - stack[*sp+1];
      break;

    case MUL:
      (*sp)--;
      stack[*sp] = stack[*sp] * stack[*sp+1];
      break;

    case DIV:
      (*sp)--;
      stack[*sp] = stack[*sp] / stack[*sp+1];
      break;

    case ODD:
      stack[*sp] = stack[*sp] % 2;
      break;

    case MOD:
      (*sp)--;
      stack[*sp] = stack[*sp] % stack[(*sp)+1];
      break;

    case EQL:
      (*sp)--;
      stack[*sp] = stack[*sp] == stack[*sp+1];
      break;

    case NEQ:
      (*sp)--;
      stack[*sp] = stack[*sp] != stack[*sp+1];
      break;

    case LSS:
      (*sp)--;
      stack[*sp] = stack[*sp] < stack[*sp+1];
      break;

    case LEQ:
      (*sp)--;
      stack[*sp] = stack[*sp] <= stack[*sp+1];
      break;

    case GTR:
      (*sp)--;
      stack[*sp] = stack[*sp] > stack[*sp+1];
      break;

    case GEQ:
      (*sp)--;
      stack[*sp] = stack[*sp] >= stack[*sp+1];
      break;
    }
    break;

  case LOD:
    stack[++*sp] = stack[base(ir.l, *bp, stack) + ir.m];
    break;

  case STO:
    stack[base(ir.l, *bp, stack) + ir.m] = stack[(*sp)--];
    break;

  case CAL:
    arlist[(*arcntr)++] = *sp + 1;
    stack[*sp + 1] = base(ir.l, *bp, stack);
    stack[*sp + 2] = *bp;
    stack[*sp + 3] = *pc - 1;
    *bp = *sp + 1;
    *pc = ir.m;
    break;

  case INC:
    *sp = *sp + ir.m;
    break;

  case JMP:
    *pc = ir.m;
    break;

  case JPC:
    if(!stack[(*sp)--])
      *pc = ir.m;
    break;

  case SOI:
    printf("%d\n", stack[(*sp)--]);
    break;

  case SIO:
    scanf("%d", &stack[++(*sp)]);
    break;
  }

  return 1; //A non-zero return value keeps the machine running
}
```

Comment: increment the pc THEN call `execOp`. Or store pc value before `execOp` and if changed, don't increment...

Comment: consider incrementing PC right after the instruction fetch, but before interpreting the instruction.  Instructions that change PC will write over the incremented value

Comment: Move PC incrementing into `execOp`. For most instructions it will do `(*pc++)`, but for jump instructions it does something else.

Comment: @infixed If there are PC-relative addressing modes, incrementing the PC before interpreting the instruction could cause a problem.

Comment: @Barmar or the definition of what is pc-relative could take that into account.  Is it relative to pre-fetch PC or post-fetch PC.  Compilers are pretty flexible at generating code and could deal with either

Comment: Well, you didn't share enough of your code to have someone able to reproduce anything, but from the look of it (your "while(running) { ... }" loop), I would simply try to chase down why your call to "execOp(...)" in your if statement's condition seems to stubbornly return something that is never 0 (or FALSE, or NULL...) -- indeed, your "running" variable never getting a chance to become a "*falsy*", once you entered that while-loop, seems to be the only reason why your code gets stuck in there, no?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre incrementing before messes with the answer, checking if changed puts it into an infinite loop.

Comment: @infixed that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Barmer I think I've done that before and it didn't work but I'll try again. EDIT: yeah that just puts it in an infinite loop too

Comment: @YSharp it stops fine normally its just certain cases make it do that

Comment: You are declaring `execOp()` and its parameter types before calling it in `main()`, right?  ( It's probably time to whip out the debugger and start single-stepping)

Comment: To paraphrase YSharp.  You do realize that `return 1; //A non-zero return value keeps the machine running
` at the end of `execOp` does imply running your `while` loop forever.  Any kind of HALT instruction?

Comment: @infixed There is a halt instruction yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of your instruction decode `select` statement seems wrong

```
  case CAL:
    arlist[(*arcntr)++] = *sp + 1;
    stack[*sp + 1] = base(ir.l, *bp, stack);
    stack[*sp + 2] = *bp;
    stack[*sp + 3] = *pc - 1;
    *bp = *sp + 1;
    *pc = ir.m;
    break;
```

Normally you'd want to return to the NEXT instruction on a return.

**`stack[*sp + 3] = *pc - 1;`**

The `*pc-1` part will probably will bring you back to your call instruction on return

I'd expect you'd want to push the address of the next instruction instead.

You'll probably want to update the stack pointer by 3 after pushing all that too, as well as checking your BP logic too

Comment: That might have been left over as one of the fixes I tried. I'll take a closer look

Comment: Ok what you suggested plus some other things that I just did seemed to have worked. My (stack) answer seems to not be completely correct so I'll have to double check all my functions but it seems to be going through the correct order of them now at least. Thanks!